# How to store data in file system when user installed the app built with cordova on android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android app using cordova/phonegap. And it should have the offline capability. I want my initial data get packaged with other file into the apk file, and when user install the app the initial data would copy to somewhere in the file system for later usage. But after searching around, I still don't figure out how to achieve this.

Is there possible to do that or I am total wrong about that? All I want to do is give the app initial data to use.

Comment: What kind of data is it? Will localStorage be good for you? You could store your initial data in JSON object, stringify and then `setItem` into localStorage. Then you could `removeItem` when you've used it. Try it out, if you get stuck, I can help.

Comment: @Keval I think localStorage don't suit me in that my data is a zip file. It consists of some assets I want to update in future. For I can't update assets file in `android_asset` folder, I have to download a zip file, unzip it to somewhere in sdcard and then access that from asset file. Perhaps my logic it totally wrong, is there some best practice to deal with this?

Comment: it is possible, search for jsStorage.js file on web.

Comment: @Aniruddha I want to store that data in android file system not in browser.

Comment: @Aniruddha, the OP wants to store a **zip** file. You can use Cordova's File System and File Transfer plugins for reading, saving or updating files into your app's folders. If the zip file's size is more, my approach would be to download the zip file into my app's folder from within the app after installation. Packaging it with the app increases the size and devices with low memory face this issue when user is installing the app and package size is high.

Comment: @Keval Agree with you, but when you say "download the zip file into my app's folder from within the app after installation.", does it achieved by programming invoke some hooks? How can I achieve download zip file even users have not open the app? I want there's always be some data even without network connection.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you must be able to access your app's files using JS within the www folder, just like you access CSS and HTML. Try reading the file and process it.

Comment: @Keval Yeah, I do achieve this thing, the problem I have is how to invoke download zip action using cordova when user install the app. I mean, automatically download zip file even user haven't open it.

Comment: Nah, that would make things very complex, if in case that was possible. You can give a first-time *Initializing* screen and do that?